# Mongo database call returning incorrect data after reload

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, graphql

I am trying to sort some database entries based on a boolean representing if a job is "completed" or not. The mutation functionality is working every time according to the graphQL playground but when the database call is utilized in the application the boolean data console logs as true first but then quickly logs again as false. The playground returns the data as true every time, once it has been changed, but something inside the application is not playing nice. Me and my project partners are freshly out of a coding bootcamp and have been learning successfully at a pretty steady pace but have not been able to figure this one out. Any feedback is appreciated. Thanks!!

```
  const { loading: userLoading, data } = useQuery(QUERY_ME_BASIC);
  const { loading: jobsLoading, data: jobsData } = useQuery(GET_JOBS);

  var user = {};
  var jobs = [];
  var completedJobs = [];
  var incompleteJobs = [];

  if (!userLoading) {
    console.log(jobsData)
    user = data.me;
  }

  if(!jobsLoading){
    jobs = jobsData.jobs
  }

  if(jobs){
    console.log(jobs)

    for (let i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
      if (jobs[i].completed === false) {
        incompleteJobs.push(jobs[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Query Response (GET_JOBS) from Graphql playground

```
{
  "data": {
    "jobs": [
      {
        "id": "47",
        "_id": "6107fce77f7afc40e4e185a7",
        "date": "2021-08-17",
        "category": "Yard Waste",
        "description": "addas",
        "distance": "1.585",
        "taken": true,
        "completed": true,
        "phone": "6153050246",
        "email": "wfh2d88@gmail.com",
        "driverEmail": "wfh2d88@gmail.com",
        "createdAt": "Aug 2nd, 2021 at 9:10 am",
        "pickup": {
          "address": "207 Porter Village Circle",
          "address2": "A",
          "city": "Nashville",
          "state": "Tennessee",
          "zip": "37206",
          "lat": "36.182571",
          "lng": "-86.733267"
        },
        "dropoff": {
          "address": "1800 Stratford Ave",
          "address2": "A",
          "city": "Nashville",
          "state": "Alabama",
          "zip": "37206",
          "lat": "36.198164",
          "lng": "-86.717083"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

console.log(job) after Job Completion (3 appear one quickly after the other). First Two:

```
0:
category: "Yard Waste"
completed: true
createdAt: "Aug 2nd, 2021 at 9:10 am"
date: "2021-08-17"
description: "addas"
distance: "1.585"
driverEmail: "wfh2d88@gmail.com"
dropoff: {address: "1800 Stratford Ave", address2: "A", city: "Nashville", state: "Alabama", zip: "37206", …}
email: "wfh2d88@gmail.com"
id: "47"
phone: "6153050246"
pickup: {address: "207 Porter Village Circle", address2: "A", city: "Nashville", state: "Tennessee", zip: "37206", …}
taken: true
__typename: "Job"
_id: "6107fce77f7afc40e4e185a7"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
Profile.js:32 
Object
Profile.js:41
```

Last log from same line:

```
0:
category: "Yard Waste"
completed: false
createdAt: "Aug 2nd, 2021 at 9:10 am"
date: "2021-08-17"
description: "addas"
distance: "1.585"
driverEmail: "wfh2d88@gmail.com"
dropoff: {address: "1800 Stratford Ave", address2: "A", city: "Nashville", state: "Alabama", zip: "37206", …}
email: "wfh2d88@gmail.com"
id: "47"
phone: "6153050246"
pickup: {address: "207 Porter Village Circle", address2: "A", city: "Nashville", state: "Tennessee", zip: "37206", …}
taken: true
__typename: "Job"
_id: "6107fce77f7afc40e4e185a7"
```

Comment: mutation response? update option code?

Comment: I added the mutation response from graphql playground as well as the console.logs from the browswer. Thanks so much for reading!

Comment: I guess get_jobs is not a mutation ... don't care about playground responses (not a mutation especially) - check dev tools network query response for MUTATION (changing state operation, show code) - prove the change is BE/API 'accepted'

Comment: Yeh  GET_JOBS is a query, my bad. When I complete a job in the browser the dev tools network says status 200 for all methods. Is this what i am looking for?

Comment: figured it out! thanks for your help